# Android : Complete action with.. for loading webview

Tags: android, android-webview, android-websettings

I use WebChromeClient for loading a webpage. It works fine for some url but for some others url, an Android menu is displayed "Complete action with..." and i must to choose between contextual navigator, Chrome or default navigator.

I would like to load in internal (in my app) each of url.
Here is the code :

```
mWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webViewArticle);
        mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                if(progress < 100 && progressB.getVisibility() == ProgressBar.GONE){
                    progressB.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
                }
                progressB.setProgress(progress);
                if(progress == 100) {
                    progressB.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
        mWebView.loadUrl(mUrl);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about WebChromeClient, one alternative is:

`mWebView.setWebViewClient`

Change from a `WebChromeCLient` to a `WebViewClient` then override `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView, java.lang.String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url) {   
 view.loadUrl(url);
 return false;
}
```

---

If you need loading done by the `WebChromeClient` you could try this:

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new YourWebChromeClient()); 
webView.setWebViewClient(new YourWebViewClient());
```

Comment: Yes, it's a solution, but onProgressChanged is not define for WebViewClient if ?

Comment: Guess you have to deal with loading yourself with a `WebViewClient`. Or try setting both clients